# MASM binary password match check

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I am trying to make a program that receives an input password and checks if it matches or not. But I can't seem to find a way to match `key` variable with `pTxt` I receive from input. Right now I am trying to do it just with strings, no binaries, but I quite do not understand how to match those 2 variables, no matter what I do the password is always "wrong". I tried debugging it by printing variables to **.txt** file: `pTxt` just has an output of exactly what I gave in input, but I could not find a way for `key` variable to just write `pass` letters in this file, it is always weird numbers. Also if someone could show an easy way to transform both variables to binary code before comparing, that would also be nice.

Here is the code, but the program also has some resource files for dialog windows, so I am just attaching a **.asm** file.

```
    include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc                            ; main system include file
    .686p
    .MMX
    .XMM

    DlgProc PROTO :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD                       ; main dialog prototype
    TxtProc PROTO :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD                       ; text dialog prototype

  ; --------------------
  ; GLOBAL scope handles
  ; --------------------
    .data
      key dd 'pass',0
    .data?
      hInstance  dd ?
      hWnd       dd ?
      hGroup     dd ?
      hButn1     dd ?
      hButn2     dd ?

    ; ----------------
    ; text dlg handles
    ; ----------------
      dlgEd     dd ?
      butn1     dd ?
      butn2     dd ?

    .code

; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤

start:
    mov hInstance, rv(GetModuleHandle, NULL)

    invoke DialogBoxParam,hInstance,100,0,ADDR DlgProc,0

    invoke ExitProcess,eax

; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤

DlgProc proc hWin:DWORD,uMsg:DWORD,wParam:DWORD,lParam:DWORD

    LOCAL pTxt  :DWORD
    LOCAL buffer[260]:BYTE

      switch uMsg
        case WM_INITDIALOG
          m2m hWnd, hWin                                            ; Copy hWin to GLOBAL variable
          invoke SendMessage,hWin,WM_SETICON,1, \
                 rv(LoadIcon,hInstance,500)

        ; -------------------------------------------
        ; Get the handle for each main dialog control
        ; -------------------------------------------
          mov hGroup, rv(GetDlgItem,hWin,101)
          mov hButn1, rv(GetDlgItem,hWin,102)
          mov hButn2, rv(GetDlgItem,hWin,103)

          xor eax, eax
          ret

      case WM_COMMAND
        switch wParam
          case 102
          ; |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

            lea eax, buffer                                         ; load buffer address
            mov pTxt, eax                                           ; cast it to a pointer
            invoke DialogBoxParam,hInstance,200,0,ADDR TxtProc,pTxt ; pass pointer to text dialog
          ; ----------------------------------------------------
          ; result if not cancelled is in buffer at pTxt address
          ; ----------------------------------------------------
            invoke lstrcmp, addr pTxt, key
            .if eax == 0 
              fn MessageBox,hWin,pTxt,"Result",MB_OK
            .else 
              fn MessageBox,hWin,"Wrong password!","Result",MB_OK
            .endif 

          ; |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

          case 103
            jmp exit_dialog                                         ; the Close button
        endsw

      case WM_CLOSE
        exit_dialog:                                                ; exit from this label
        invoke EndDialog,hWin,0

      endsw

    xor eax, eax                                                    ; zero eax on exit
    ret

DlgProc endp

; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤

TxtProc proc hWin:DWORD,uMsg:DWORD,wParam:DWORD,lParam:DWORD

      switch uMsg
        case WM_INITDIALOG
        ; -------------------------------------------
        ; Get the handle for each text dialog control
        ; -------------------------------------------
          mov dlgEd, rv(GetDlgItem,hWin,201)
          mov butn1, rv(GetDlgItem,hWin,202)
          mov butn2, rv(GetDlgItem,hWin,203)

        .data?
          pbuf@@@@ dd ?                                             ; decorate to prevent accidental duplicates
        .code

        mov eax, lParam                                             ; lParam is the passed memory pointer
        mov pbuf@@@@, eax                                           ; store address passed in lParam

        case WM_COMMAND
          switch wParam
            case 202
              mov eax, pbuf@@@@
              mov BYTE PTR [eax], 0                                 ; zero the buffer first

              invoke GetWindowText,dlgEd,pbuf@@@@,260               ; get any text in edit control

              mov eax, pbuf@@@@                                     ; load buffer address again
              .if BYTE PTR [eax] == 0                               ; test if its an empty string
                fn MessageBox,hWin,"No password has been entered", \
                                   "Result",MB_OK                    ; show error and don't exit
              .else
                jmp bye                                             ; normal exit with buffer address
              .endif

            case 203
          invoke EndDialog,hWin,0                                   ; return 0 on cancel
          endsw

        case WM_CLOSE
          bye:                                                      ; exit from this label
          invoke EndDialog,hWin,pbuf@@@@                            ; return the buffer address

      endsw

    xor eax, eax                                                    ; zero eax on exit
    ret

TxtProc endp

; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤

end start
```

Comment: The best way to debug asm is with a debugger that lets you single-step instructions and look at register contents.  That's much better than debug-prints because you can do it without disturbing the original code, and you can follow the path of execution visually.  Using a debugger is nearly essential- it's a waste of time to try to debug and learn asm without one.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am a very beginner in a assembly and I tried to use Olly, SASM, x64dbg, but at this level it just blews my mind. Is there a really simple one I could try to use? I heard Visual Studio has a really handy one.

Comment: I don't use Windows.  (I use GDB on Linux but it's clunky).  I think the Visual Studio debugger has a pretty reasonable asm / disassembly view.  I think Olly is good for disassembly view but maybe doesn't have a source view?  When you're using MASM's high-level macros like `invoke`, it can definitely be useful to see how those really expand into machine instructions.  Get used to it; generally if you want to write `switch` / `case` use C and a C compiler - it can pick the best way to optimize that into asm.  (And you can look at the compiler's output).

Comment: For example, your `switch wParam` with only two cases would probably be a lot simpler in asm as a couple compare/branches, unless that's what MASM already does.  (I didn't know MASM even has `switch` / `case`; I don't know if it builds a jump table or if it just chains compare / branch for you.)  If you barely know asm yet, writing a GUI in it seems like a mistake.  Maybe do that in C and call an asm function to do the interesting part (the password compare I guess).